# Permanent change of a way that R determines axes limits

Tags: r, plot

I'll start with a simple example. Code below results with boxplot with y-axis labels not covering the whole range of data.

```
x<-c(0.5, 1:5, 5.5)
boxplot(x)
```

[image]

I can easily fix that with `ylim`:

```
boxplot(x, ylim=range(pretty(x)))
```

[image]

Is there a way to make this way of calculating `ylim` default for all the plot functions in basic R (like `barplot()`, `plot()` etc.)? Maybe some clever `par()` or `options()` assigment?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I doubt it. I just took a look at the code behind `barplot()`; when ylim is not specified, it takes its cue from the range of x values. & I suspect a hack solution would be more troublesome than simply including the `ylim=range(pretty(x))` line as you have already done. I'd be the first to admit I'm rusty in R's base graphics, though. Hopefully someone else here knows better.

Comment: @Z.Lin Thank you  for your effort. Why you think that "hack solution would be more troublesome than simply including the `ylim=range(pretty(x))`"? I'm using it for quite a long time and so far it works perfectly.

Comment: That's precisely what I mean. Setting ylim explicitly with `range(pretty(x))` seems quite elegant for this use case. Other workarounds would probably require more work / be less robust.